# Docker symfony 4 permission denied when trying to pull

Tags: git, symfony, docker

I use docker to work with symfony 4 . MySQL configuration in docker-compose.yml file is :

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: sf4_mysql
    volumes:
        - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ***
        MYSQL_USER: ***
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
```

I have tried to put .docker folder in git ignore file but when i tried to commit i received this message :

```
$ git add .
error: open(".docker/data/db/ib_logfile0"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file .docker/data/db/ib_logfile0
fatal: updating files failed
```

Comment: Is `ib_logfile0` already in git?

Comment: all the .docker folder is in git i pushed this folder to make easy to run the project directly after docker-compose up -d . but now i have a serious problem with file permission and i'm enabled to pull or commit

Comment: You need to use `chmod` to modify the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a docker-compose.yml file, which defines the services like you do, i.e. mysql database, which maps a local volume (from host) to inside of a container, it creates the required folders and files for mysql to use. And gives them `root`  user as owner.

You will not be able to work with this further. I would recommend to *never* change permissions on your database folder

Best solution for you is to put the database volume aside. Somewhere else.  But not inside your project. Put it to `../.docker/data/db` or something.

Comment: thanks Alex even i don't know exactly what's the importance of puting volumes: in the docker compose file